# Yahoo OpenID Connect: "OAuth authorization code expired or invalid"

Tags: openid-connect

I am using the OpenID-Connect-PHP library and it works beautifully when Google is the IdP and using the Authorization Flow.  When Yahoo is the IdP I get an authorization code but when I submit it for the ID token I get this exception:  "OAuth authorization code expired or invalid."  It acts as if Yahoo's authorization endpoint is handing me a bad code.  I'm just fishing for anyone who has seen this or might be familiar enough with OpenID Connect to provide some suggestion.  I have posted on the Yahoo Developer Network but I routinely find answers to my questions on this forum so I thought I would post here too.  It looks like Yahoo supports OpenID Connect but I am not certain, I saw some info that made me think they only support OpenID 2.0.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The documentation reads "code: (Required) The authorization code appended to redirect_uri after calling Yahoo’s OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint." I thought maybe I misunderstood what they were talking about and actually tried to concatenate the code to the redirect_uri when passing it to the token endpoint, but of course that didn't work, either.